# Generate Sitemap from URLs in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, sitemap

**Problem Statement:**

URLs are stored in a database, example:

```
home/page1
gallery/image1
info/IT/contact
home/page2
home/page3
gallery/image2
info/IT/map
```

and so on.

I would like to arrange the above urls into a tree fashion as shown below (each item will be a url link). The final output would be a simple HTML List (plus any sub list(s))

thus:

```
home         gallery           info
  page1         image1           IT
  page2         image2            contact
  page3                           map
```

Programming Language is C# , platform is asp.net

**EDIT 1:**

In the above example, we end up with **Three** Lists because in our example there is three main 'groups' eg: home, gallery, info.

Naturally, this can change, the algorithm needs to be able to somehow build the lists recursively..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, did it:

First created a class:

```
 public class Node
 {
    private string _Parent = string.Empty;
    private string _Child = string.Empty;
    private bool   _IsRoot = false;

    public string Parent
    {
        set { _Parent = value; }
        get { return _Parent; }
    }

    public string Child
    {
        set { _Child = value; }
        get { return _Child; }
    }

    public Node(string PChild, string PParent)
    {
        _Parent = PParent;
        _Child = PChild;
    }

    public bool IsRoot
    {
        set { _IsRoot = value; }
        get { return _IsRoot; }
    }
 }
```

then generated the SiteMap, by transforming the urls strings directly as follows:

```
   private static string MakeTree()
    {
        List<Node> __myTree = new List<Node>();

        List<string> urlRecords = new List<string>();
        urlRecords.Add("home/image1");
        urlRecords.Add("home/image2");
        urlRecords.Add("IT/contact/map");
        urlRecords.Add("IT/contact/address");
        urlRecords.Add("IT/jobs");

        __myTree = ExtractNode(urlRecords);

        List<string> __roots = new List<string>();

        foreach(Node itm in __myTree)
        {
            if (itm.IsRoot)
            {
                __roots.Add(itm.Child.ToString());
            }
        }

        string __trees = string.Empty;

        foreach (string roots in __roots)
        {
            __trees += GetChildren(roots, __myTree) + "<hr/>";
        }


        return __trees;
    }

    private static string GetChildren(string PRoot, List<Node> PList)
    {
        string __res = string.Empty;
        int __Idx = 0;

        foreach (Node x in PList)
        {
            if (x.Parent.Equals(PRoot))
            {
                __Idx += 1;
            }
        }

        if (__Idx > 0)
        {
            string RootHeader = string.Empty;

            foreach (Node x in PList)
            {
                if (x.IsRoot & PRoot == x.Child)
                {
                    RootHeader = x.Child;
                }
            }

            __res += RootHeader+ "<ul>\n";

            foreach (Node itm in PList)
            {
                if (itm.Parent.Equals(PRoot))
                {
                    __res += string.Format("<ul><li>{0}{1}</li></ul>\n", itm.Child, GetChildren(itm.Child, PList));
                }
            }
            __res += "</ul>\n";
            return __res;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }

    private static List<Node> ExtractNode(List<string> Urls)
    {
        List<Node> __NodeList = new List<Node>();

        foreach (string itm in Urls)
        {
            string[] __arr = itm.Split('/');
            int __idx = -1;

            foreach (string node in __arr)
            {
                __idx += 1;
                if (__idx == 0)
                {
                    Node __node = new Node(node, "");
                    if (!__NodeList.Exists(x => x.Child == __node.Child & x.Parent == __node.Parent))
                    {
                        __node.IsRoot = true;
                        __NodeList.Add(__node);    
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Node __node = new Node(node, __arr[__idx - 1].ToString());
                    {
                        if (!__NodeList.Exists (x => x.Child == __node.Child & x.Parent == __node.Parent))
                        {
                            __NodeList.Add(__node);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return __NodeList;
    }
```

anyway it's not optimised, I'm sure I can clean it up a lot..

Answer (score 0):

Well,sorting those strings need a lot of work,I've done something similar to your condition.I wish to share the strategy with you.

First of all,(if you can change design of your tables indeed) 
Create a table URL like below

```
----------------
|   URL Table  |
----------------
|  ID          | 
|  ParentID    |
|  Page        |
|..extra info..|
----------------
```

It's an implementation of category and sub category in same table.In a similar manner,you can contain insert a lot of page and subpage.For example,

```
-------------------------------------
|  ID  |   ParentID   |    Page     | ...
 ------------------------------------
|   0  |     null     |    Home     |
|   1  |     null     |   Gallery   |
|   2  |     null     |    Info     |
|   3  |       0      |    Page1    |
|   4  |       0      |    Page2    |
|   5  |       0      |    Page3    | ...
|   6  |       1      |    Image1   |
|   7  |       1      |    Image2   |
|   8  |       2      |      IT     |
|   9  |       8      |    contact  |
|   1  |       8      |     map     |
------------------------------------- ...
```

when **ParentID** is **null** then its highest level 
when **ParentID** is and **ID** then its a sublevel of whatever level is on that ID and so on...

From C# side,you know the top pages where ParentID's are null.
You can bring sub pages of them by selected ID's of top pages.It's some ADO.NET work.

Hope this helps
Myra